# Do matrix models capture the string landscape?

Tags: string-theory, cosmological-inflation, string-theory-landscape, matrix-model, anthropic-principle

Essentially what the title asks-- are matrix models, such as BFSS, believed to capture in any way the large possible space of false string vacua, for instance as saddles in the action with nonminimal energy, in such a way that the dynamics of settling into a false vacuum/metastable state could in principle be probed with such models? This would be from the perspective of answering questions about the "cosmological prior" that people sometimes gesture to in the context of anthropic arguments for the values of certain couplings.